# GeoPandas | Legend not showing

Tags: python-3.x, plot, legend, geopandas

Goal: Show `legend`

I've set `legend=True` and no difference was made.

```
for i in list(range(NUM_SLIDES)):
    d = {'col1': ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Sue'], 'geometry': [foo[i], bar[i], sue[i]]}
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(d, crs='EPSG:4326').plot(legend=True, alpha=0.5, color=list(mcolors.BASE_COLORS.values()), aspect=1);
```

First Plot:

[image]

Comment: Must specify the option column=''col1" in .plot().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To plot/visualize a `theme` using values from a column of geodataframe you must add the option column="column_name" to the `.plot()` statement.

Swap `color` for `cmap='rainbow'`.

In your particular case,

```
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(d, crs='EPSG:4326').plot(column='col1', cmap='rainbow', legend=True, alpha=0.5, aspect=1);
```

should work.

[image]

Comment: I got a warning stating either `column` or `color`. I removed `color` and this worked :)